# How to connect to Facebook/Twitter/Google using Backand and Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, backand

From the example provided by Backand in https://github.com/backand/backand-ionic2-starter

I can see in the service ( https://github.com/backand/backand-ionic2-starter/blob/master/app/services/backandService.ts ):

```
urls:{ 
    signup:string, 
    token:string, 
    requestResetPassword: string,
    resetPassword: string,
    changePassword: string,
    socialLoginWithCode: string,
    socialSignupWithCode: string,
    socialLoginWithToken: string
} = {
    signup: '/1/user/signup',
    token: '/token',
    requestResetPassword: '/1/user/requestResetPassword',
    resetPassword: '/1/user/resetPassword',
    changePassword: '/1/user/changePassword',
    socialLoginWithCode: '/1/user/PROVIDER/code',
    socialSignupWithCode: '/1/user/PROVIDER/signupCode',
    socialLoginWithToken: '/1/user/PROVIDER/token'
};
```

So my guess is that the strings declared in socialLoginWithCode, socialSignupWithCode or socialLoginWithToken, PROVIDER should be either facebook, twitter or google, but how do I implement the functions pointing to these addresses following the best practices?

Comment: We are working on it and we will release a solution soon

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called HtAuth that has functionality to do this.